# Is there a way to tell NuGet to get the latest version?

Tags: nuget

We ship sample programs for our library. These sample programs are set to use NuGet to reference our library. Because we want the user to be using the latest version of our code in the samples, for each new version we have to go update all the samples to use the new (latest) version of our library.

Is there a way in NuGet to set the version to RELEASE like can be done in maven?

And if not, is there a way to programmatically walk all our .sln files (PowerShell?) to set them to the new version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `*` as your version number https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#floating-version-resolutions

Comment: Thank you - exactly what we need